# How to make a dict with access by my_dict.my_key?

Tags: python, dictionary

Often, it would be convenient to access dict entries with `my_dict.my_key` instead of `my_dict['my_key']`.

So I came up with the following solution:

```
class ddict(dict):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        dict.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        for (k, v) in kwargs.items():
            self.__dict__[k] = v
```

You can use it as:

```
    d = ddict(a = 1, b = 2)
    print(d.a)
    print(d.b)
```

Is that approach safe or will it bite me at some point? Is there maybe even a built-in approach?

(Why do I want that? Easier typing and looks better than a dict or an explicitly defined class, but that should not be the topic here, since it's a matter of taste and situation. And it's iterable.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better and safer way would be to use `_getattr_` (which is what Python calls when you use the `.` notation, but do note that this approach only allows for string keys (not integers, floats or arbitrary objects):

```
class ddict(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return self[item]

d = ddict()
d['a'] = 1
print(d.a)
>> 1
```

You may also override `__setattr__` so you can assign with the . notation as well.

```
class ddict(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return self[item]

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        self[key] = value

d = ddict()
d.a = 1
print(d.a)
>> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override `__getattr__`

```
class ddict(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return self[item]

a=ddict({'a':'12'})
a.a
```

Will output `'12'`

To mention it's better to use [`UserDict`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#userdict-objects) from [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html) module

So you can override make your class more clear:

```
from collections import UserDict

class ddict(UserDict):
    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return self.data[item]
```

But this will resting using `data` as variable name in your `ddict` object, since it will be returning the whole `dict` object.

And as @DeepSpace noted, you probably would want to override `__setattr__` to be able to set value though name.

Comment: Inheriting from `UserDict` will somehow run into an infinite recursion, while inheriting from `dict` works.